# Using Communication style "clear" in Jmeter JMS point to point sampler

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

As per http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Point-to-Point

the communication style clear is used to clear the messages from the given queue.

```
Scenario: In my test plan , i have 2 threadgroups. 
1) JMS Point to Point sampler to send messages: My JMS sampler fires request_only messages to the inqueue.
2) JMS Point to Point sampler to clear the messages in the outqueue. Here the communication style is selected as "clear" and the outqueue has been specified in the "JNDI Request queue" field.
```

On running the test plan almost always the View results tree shows that the clear JMS sampler has cleared 0 messages from the outqueue.

Any idea why this is so.

My objective is to ensure that the outqueue is drained regularly. Please advise if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter 4.0 supports [clear](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) option in JMS

> JMS Point-to-Point sampler has been enhanced with read, browse, clear options.

So you can choose communication style `clear`

[image]